# Php newbie, how to get php variable from new html form

Tags: php, html, forms, server

hello I'm trying to use a form to post variables from an index.html to an action_page.php then somehow get those variables from a new results.html page (is this possible to do?)

my index form looks like this

```
<form action="action_page.php" method="post">
<select name="race" style="width: 180px;">
<option value="White">White</option>
<option value="Asian">Asian</option> // 
</select>

edit: 
<p><input type="submit" value="formSubmit" name="formSubmit"></p>

</form> </p> <!-- there is a lot more code in between -->
```

my php looks like this

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["formSubmit"]) )
{
  $varRace = $_POST["race"];

echo $varRace; // this doesn't work why?

}

function redirect($url, $statusCode = 303)
{
header('location: ' .$url, true, $statusCode);
die();
}
$varRedirect = "results.html";
// call to function removed but it would call redirect($varRedirect);
?>
```

ultimately i'd like my results.html page to display a variable $varRace for instance.

since forms post to themselves is this possible to get ? is there a php function I could write to send the variable?

Comment: If that's all your HTML you have a few problems: you haven't closed the `<form>` tag; there's no input with a name of `formSubmit` (which means that the test that checks for it will always fail); there's no `<input>` named `age`. If that's _not_ all your HTML, post the entire form so we can get a clear idea of what's happening.

Comment: there is a lot in the form I edited the question to account for the closing form tag and formSubmit button  and removed age

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do that using cookies get posted data from action_page.php and set data to cookie value called race end after that inside the results.html you can get that value and print that on the results.html
and after that delete cookie(set past expire time)

**#** first close ***form*** tag and add  ***input type="submit"*** to your form

```
<form action="action_page.php" method="post">
 <select name="race" style="width: 180px;">
 <option value="White">White</option>
 <option value="Asian">Asian</option> // 
 </select>
<input type="submit" name="formSubmit" value="submit">>
</form>
```

change **action_page.php**

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST["formSubmit"]) )
    {
    $varRace = $_POST["race"];
    setcookie("race", $varRace, time()+600);
    $varRedirect = "results.html";
    redirect($varRedirect);
    }

    function redirect($url, $statusCode = 303)
    {
        header('location: '.$url, true, $statusCode);
    }

 ?>
```

**results.html**

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function init() {
            var race = getCookie('race');
                document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = race;
                document.cookie = "race=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC"; 
        }

function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1);
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) return c.substring(name.length,c.length);
    }
    return "";
} 
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="init()">
    your race is :
    <p id='test'></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what is the expires param that you added onto the document.cookie string ? is this required?

Comment: no it is not required without that your race value is store in client side 600ms (10sec)

Comment: this worked great thanks!!! is it safer to post to a .html file than a .php? results.html > results.php ??

Comment: using results.php you can do that simply set session variable in action_page.php and print that in results.php this is not a good method u asked about results.html that's why i post this method :)

Comment: if user blocked cookies in his browser your web page not working properly there for if u can use results.php instead of using results.html... don't use this method use sessions 
[sessions w3school](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp)

Comment: is html any safer though? because can't malicious code be appended to the end of a php file?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72459/discussion-between-alupotha-and-ryan-williams).